# Odoo adding a Treeview web controller

Tags: treeview, odoo-9, web-controls

I've been hammering away at this specific problem for at least 3 days and coulnd't figure out where I'm supposed to modify to add new action to a specific tree view.

[image: I'm talking about this item/menu]

Has far as I know, it's supposed to be a webcontroller but I don't know where to modify ( Do I do it in my .py or .xml file? ) 
Is there any way I can add a new action to this? 
If you know any anwser please be as specific as you can, because there's is none about this that I could find helpfull.

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself:

> 1) Go to the xml file you want to modify the treeview 
>   2) Add the following code

```
<act_window 
    name="New Sub menu" 
    res_model="<target.model>" 
    src_model="<source.model>"
    key2="client_action_multi"  <!-- This will make it show on the "More" -->
    <!-- "client_print_multi" => Will make it show on the "Print" -->
    view_mode="form"
    target="new" 
    view_type="form"
    id="act_new_sub_menu" 
/>
```

[image]